# Lua return multiple values as arguments

Tags: function, lua, return, arguments, multiple-arguments

I have a function (that I cannot change) returning multiple values :

```
function f1()
    ...
    return a, b
end
```

and another function (that I cannot change) taking multiple arguments :

```
function f2(x, y, z)
    ...
end
```

is there a way to do :

```
f2(f1(), c)
```

and have **x** be **a**,  **y** be **b** and **z** be **c** ?

Comment: Well sadly no it doesn't work (I'm using love2D)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it in one line because `f2(f1(),c)` adjusts the results returned by `f1` to a single value.

Answer (score 2):

You could use intermediate results

```
local a, b = f1()
f2(a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a table as a helper:

```
tbl={f1()}
tbl[3]=c
f2(unpack(tbl))
```